# Selecting only columns where sum(column) > 0

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table like this:

```
Date     Bob     Joe     Will
1/1/15    1       0        1
1/2/15    0       0        1
1/3/15    0       0        0
1/4/15    1       1        1
```

**Preferred solution**

With one statement, I want to return *only* the columns where `SUM(Column) > 0`

For example:

```
SELECT SUM(Bob) as Robert, SUM(Joe) as Joseph, SUM(Will) as William
  FROM table
 WHERE Date BETWEEN '1/1/15' and '1/3/15'
```

I want my result to look like this:

```
Robert     William
  1           2
```

In other words, since `SUM(Joe) = 0` for my selected date range, I don't want the column `Joseph` to appear in the result set. What is the magic that would cause `Joseph` to not appear?

**Alternate Solution**

I can work with the data if it comes back slightly differently, so I have considered writing a table function to return a 2-column table like this:

```
Name        Value
Robert      1
William     2
```

My thought is that the function code would look similar to this:

```
--Declare table here
IF SELECT SUM(Bob) > 0
  INSERT INTO temp (Name, Value)
    ('Robert', SELECT SUM(Bob))
```

Lather, rinse, repeat for each of my columns. I know this isn't ideal since it would need maintenance should there ever be a new column that needs to considered, but there's other maintenance in that situation anyway, so I could handle it.

**In Summary**

Is there a way to create a query that would give me my preferred solution? If not, are my thoughts on my alternate solution reasonable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This solution gives you your "Alternate Solution" answer.  The only way to achieve what you are looking for as a primary solution would be a dynamic pivot operation on the result set after you have unpivoted it.  This solution does require maintenance but is straightforward and no function is required.

**Sample data:**

```
DECLARE @Names TABLE
    (
      DateValue DATE NOT NULL
    , Bob INT NOT NULL
    , Joe INT NOT NULL
    , Will INT NOT NULL
    );

DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '1/1/2015';
DECLARE @MaxDate DATE = '1/3/2015';
DECLARE @MinValue INT = 1;

INSERT  INTO @Names
        ( DateValue, Bob, Joe, Will )
VALUES  ( '1/1/2015', 1, 0, 1 )
        , ( '1/2/2015', 0, 0, 1 )
        , ( '1/3/2015', 0, 0, 0 )
        , ( '1/4/2015', 1, 1, 1 );
```

**Query:**

```
WITH    CTE_Unpivot
          AS ( SELECT   DateValue
                      , ScoreName
                      , Scores
               FROM     ( SELECT    DateValue
                                    , Bob
                                    , Joe
                                    , Will
                          FROM      @Names
                        ) AS cp 
               UNPIVOT  ( Scores FOR ScoreName IN ( Bob, Joe, Will ) ) AS up
             )
    SELECT  ScoreName
          , SUM(Scores) AS ScoreTotal
    FROM    CTE_Unpivot
    WHERE   DateValue BETWEEN @MinDate AND @MaxDate
    GROUP BY ScoreName
    HAVING  SUM(Scores) >= @MinValue;
```

**Edit:**
Ideally, you wouldn't have the table stored like that, it looks like it was copied from an Excel spreadsheet.  You would have a table with three columns, date, name and value, then query based on that.